# Ruby Count lines in file including last line(empty)

Tags: ruby, file, io, eof

I'm trying to count the lines of a file with ruby but I can't get either `IO` or `File` to count the last line.
What do I mean by last line?
Here's a screenshot of Atom editor getting that last line
[image]

Ruby returns 20 lines, I need 21 lines. Here is such file
https://copy.com/cJbiAS4wxjsc9lWI

Comment: can you post how are you counting the number of lines?

Comment: You could simply add 1 (`File.foreach('file.txt').count + 1`) to match the text editor's last line number.

Comment: There is no 21'st line. What do you see in editor as a 21'st line is a `\n` at the end of 20's line. So, the right answer is: there are 20 lines in this file.

Comment: It's 21 lines only if you count the red one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question (although your example file is cumbersome). Your editor shows a 21st line because the 20th line *ends* with a newline character. Without a trailing newline character, your editor would show 20 lines.

Here's a simpler example:

```
a = "foo\nbar"
b = "baz\nqux\n"
```

A text editor would show:

```
# file a
1 foo
2 bar

# file b
1 baz
2 qux
3
```

Ruby however sees 2 lines in either cases:

```
a.lines       #=> ["foo\n", "bar"]
a.lines.count #=> 2

b.lines       #=> ["baz\n", "qux\n"]
b.lines.count #=> 2
```

You could trick Ruby into recognizing the trailing newline by adding an arbitrary character:

```
(a + '_').lines       #=> ["foo\n", "bar_"]
(a + '_').lines.count #=> 2

(b + '_').lines       #=> ["baz\n", "qux\n", "_"]
(b + '_').lines.count #=> 3
```

Or you could use a `Regexp` that matches either end of line (`$`) or end of string (`\Z`):

```
a.scan(/$|\Z/)       #=> ["", ""]
a.scan(/$|\Z/).count #=> 2

b.scan(/$|\Z/)       #=> ["", "", ""]
b.scan(/$|\Z/).count #=> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby `lines` method doesn't count the last empty line.
To trick, you can add an arbitrary character at the end of your stream.

Ruby `lines` returns 2 lines for this example:

```
1 Hello
2 World
3
```

Instead, it returns 3 lines in this case

```
1 Hello
2 World
3 *
```